# Add 90 days to a Y-m-d H:i:s formatted date, in Unix Timestamp format

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, strtotime

How can I add 90 days to a `Y-m-d H:i:s` formatted date that's pre-defined and convert it to a Unix Timestamp so I can send it as an expiration argument for `setcookie()`?

I've tried the following:

```
var_dump(strtotime('+90 days', '1994-02-21 08:01:13'));
```

Which outputs:

> **Notice:** A non well formed numeric value encountered in [file path] on line **3**.
>
> int(7777994)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) expects a timestamp, not a string. In other words, you need to call `strtotime()` on the second parameter, like so:

```
var_dump(strtotime('+90 days', strtotime('1994-02-21 08:01:13')));
```

A simpler solution (without using the second parameter) is possible as well:

```
var_dump(strtotime('1994-02-21 08:01:13 +90 days'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Using DateTime you can swap between unix timestamp or format easily.

```
$date = new DateTime("1994-02-21 08:01:13");
$date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString("90 days"));
var_dump($date->getTimestamp()); // Prints: int(769593673)
//var_dump($date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")); // Prints: 1994-05-22 08:01:13
```

Comment: @salathe weirdy beardy spacing was there for readability. Personal preference of formatting, prevents me from messing up. Sorry you didn't like it, but hardly needed to be edited out as it didn't impact the code running correctly and made it very clear which part belonged where. My 5 cents on this edit of yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

I converted my answer into a function that defaults to 90 days, but will accept any number of days.
It's up to the next coder to work out any error correction / detection

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

function add_days($input,$days=90){
   $timestamp=strtotime($input);
   $future = $timestamp + (60*60*24*$days);
   //$future_string = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $future);
   //return $future_string;
   return $future;
 }

echo add_days('1994-02-21 08:01:13'); // default 90
echo "\n";
echo add_days('1994-02-21 08:01:13',10);  // 10, just to show a non-default return
```

Otuput:

<s>1994-05-22 09:01:13</s>
<s>1994-03-03 08:01:13</s>

```
769611673
762699673
```